# Check slot is available between two date

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: DATABASE TABLE STRUCTURE]

I am making car rental portal.

For new booking, I have to check that car (`v_id`) is available for that slot ( booking starting data and ending date).

I don't know how to check available slot by starting date and ending date in.

Comment: To start, I would suggest not SHOUTING your problem at the users, but writing but calmly. Next, you need to figure out what RDBMS you are using. You've tagged both SQL Server and MySQL which are 2 very different products; that screenshot looks like MySQL. Talking of your Screenshot, please don't post images of data. Data is text and should be posted as `text`. Finally, what is your question exactly? You've said you don't know how to do something, but haven't asked anything. What have you tried (post your code), what are your expected results?

Comment: You also need to define availability, given that 'unavailability' is clearly not a factor when considering whether or not a booking can be made for a given timeslot.

Comment: How you define car slot details. Is it a predefined slots? Like 9.00 AM to 10.00 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at the BETWEEN Operator

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between
- [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Search the table for entries WHERE the `'new start date'` OR the `'new end date'` is BETWEEN a `'stored start date'` AND a `'stored end date'`.

If you get 0 results, the range is free.